# Azure KeyVault throws 401 unauthorized error but the response still has 200 status and correct data

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault

I registered an app with name **TestApp1** to azure active directory using **Accounts in this organizational directory only (Default Directory only - Single tenant)** and no Redirect URI.
Along with the application I created an application secret.

Afterwards i created an Azure Key Vault with name **KVtest** and created a certificate.

Then i went to **KVtest Access Control (IAM)** option and added a role of **contributor** to my **TestApp1**.
After that, i went to **access policy** option and added a policy with template **Key,Secret & Certificate Management** and selected as **Principal** my **TestApp1**

Right now i am testing this Azure configuration using the following :

```
        const string certificate = "testCertificate";
        var myKeyVaultName = "KVtest";
        var kvUri = $"https://KVtest.vault.azure.net/";
        string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];
        string clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"];
        string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureTenantId"];
        var clientSecretCred = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
        var certClient = new CertificateClient(new Uri(kvUri), clientSecretCred);
        var AZcertificate = certClient.GetCertificate(certificate);
```

The last line throws a **401 (unauthorized)** exception but when i continue with debugging step by step the value stored at AZcertificate has an Azure.Response object with status 200 and correct data.

Is this the correct behavior?
Is this an error to azure configuration?

Nuget packages used:

[image]

Comment: Two things I’d check - make sure the certificate actually exists and make sure the template includes the GET permission for certificates. Here’s the source code for that https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/945b2b22cb1b118e966ed6abc8bd92d5af6fd20f/sdk/keyvault/Azure.Security.KeyVault.Certificates/src/CertificateClient.cs#L354

Comment: The certificate exists and the template has GET permission. I copied the certificate's name to be sure.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, the reason behind getting `401` error is using ***trailing slash*** at the end of the Key Vault resource URI

```cs
var kvUri = $"https://KVtest.vault.azure.net/";
```

Other resource URIs can work with or without trailing slash but Key Vault resource URI doesn't work with it.

***To resolve it, try removing the trailing slash as below:***

```cs
var kvUri = $"https://KVtest.vault.azure.net";
```

#### Other reasons for getting 401 unauthorized error are:

1. ***Lack of access token*** : Make sure whether the client is sending access token with every request to the Key Vault, Otherwise it will reject the request with `401` error.
2. ***Bad token*** : If the token is expired , invalid or incorrect resource URI, then it causes `401` error.

***For more information in detail, please refer these links if they are helpful:***

[AZIdentity | Azure Key Vault OAuth Resource Value: https://vault.azure.net (no slash!)](https://azidentity.azurewebsites.net/post/2018/11/30/azure-key-vault-oauth-resource-value-https-vault-azure-net-no-slash)

[AZIdentity | Key Vault Client: Why am I seeing HTTP 401?](https://azidentity.azurewebsites.net/post/2019/07/31/key-vault-client-why-am-i-seeing-http-401)

Comment: The slash in this case is fine as it is part of the Key Vault URL.  The Resource URL when obtaining an access token is where the slash becomes problematic.

Answer (score -1):

But if you have an expired token, incorrect or invalid resource URI, the payload should not have the valid values.  I've seen this same behavior, and it only happens on the first call to key vault and the secret retrieved doesn't matter.  I am having the same issue, but in my case, there is no trailing slash, but the 401 shows up, the payload is correct.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34983822)